# Lcov not counting function toplines

Tags: clang, code-coverage, lcov

I am using lcov to generate coverage information for the project I am working on. It is mostly working, except for some reason it seems to not count the function toplines in every single case. This means that class files that have complete test coverage will still have a few lines missing and so show like 90%.

It isn't a big deal but it is kind of annoying. I wonder if anyone has any idea why.

Below I've provided a complete minimal example demonstrating this problem. When this program is run, 4 lines are 'hit' out of 6 lines, leaving me with 68.7% line coverage, despite the fact that all lines are clearly executed.

GCOV output

```
Summary coverage rate:
  lines......: 66.7% (4 of 6 lines)
  functions..: 100.0% (2 of 2 functions)
  branches...: no data found
```

### Example

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(NAME MinTest)

project (${NAME})

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.2)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS
"--coverage -O0 -g")

add_executable(
  ${NAME}
  src/main.c
)
```

src/main.c

```
void function() {
  printf("foo");
}

int main(void) {
  function();
}
```

runWithCoverageInfo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 = source root
# $2 = build directory

if [ ! -d "coverage" ]; then
    echo "Creating coverage directory...";
    mkdir coverage;
else
    find ./coverage -name *.info -exec rm {} \;;
fi;

echo "Removing previous coverage output files...";
find $2 -name *.gcda -exec rm {} \;;

echo "Analysing baseline coverage data...";
lcov --initial --no-external --capture --base-directory $2 --directory $2 --directory $1 --output-file coverage/coverage_base.info ;

echo "Running tests...";
./MinTest;
returnCode=$?

echo "Generating coverage output";
lcov --capture  --no-external --directory $2 --directory $1 --base-directory $2 --output-file coverage/coverage_test.info --quiet ;
lcov -a coverage/coverage_base.info -a coverage/coverage_test.info -output-file coverage/coverage_total.info --quiet;
lcov --summary coverage/coverage_total.info;
genhtml coverage/coverage_total.info --output-directory coverage -quiet;

exit $returnCode;
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example which has incomplete coverage and compile options?

Comment: @Gluttton thanks for the reply. Check my edit :)

Comment: In my environment: LCOV version 1.11, gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010 using your source code, build script and script for generate coverage data I have got 100% coverage.

Comment: Have you tried clean your build directory and recreate `*.gcda` and `*.gcno` files?

Comment: @Glutton I'm using clang not GCC though

Comment: `I'm using clang`, yep, you are right. With clang Ubuntu clang version 3.6.2-1 I get error: `geninfo: ... main.c.gcno: reached unexpected end of file`. Sorry, looks like I can't help anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, LCOV defaulted to providing branch coverage.  It does not anymore.  (At least, the version I have [1.12] does not.)  So you have to explicitly tell it in your `lcov` and `genhtml` commands to generate branch reports.  For example:

```
lcov -d . --zerocounters
lcov -d . --rc lcov_branch_coverage=1 --no-external --capture -o ../reports/myproj.info
cd ../reports
genhtml --branch-coverage myproj.info
```

The `--rc lcov_branch_coverage=1` in the LCOV command and `--branch-coverage` in the HTML generation command are required for branch coverage analysis/reporting.

You could opt to put `lcov_branch_coverage=1` and `genhtml_branch_coverage=1` in your `.lcovrc` resource file if you want to always default to branch coverage.  See lcovrc(5) manpage for more details, or online here:  http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcovrc.5.php

Comment: I no longer have my project setup in order to be able to test that. But this looks like the answer I was looking for... (where were you 2 months ago ;) ) so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I only started using LCOV a month ago, so would not have looked at this back when it was more relevant to you (sorry).  When I answered this, I was going through every question with the `lcov` tag trying to find an answer to another problem I was having when I saw your post and thought I might have some helpful information for you.  Thanks for the "accept."